# Reopen this mistakenly-closed-as-duplicate question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

The question [Short story where man rejected from learning program and identified as untrainable](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127087/short-story-where-man-rejected-from-learning-program-and-identified-as-untrainab) was closed as a duplicate of [Story where the protagonist is turned off from an automated system of professional attribution and instant learning](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession).

The latter question has an accepted answer, while the former answer doesn't.

Site policy is that questions should not be closed as duplicates of each other if they [don't both have accepted answers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/32390).

Can we reopen the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127087/short-story-where-man-rejected-from-learning-program-and-identified-as-untrainab)?

Comment: For story id i personally think we should give the op a couple of days-weeks to accept before duping it  since there could in theory be multipule books that could answer a story ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The question has been reopened by @Himarm and @user14111, and I just left a comment reminding users of the policy on dupe-closing story-ID questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's clearly obvious that the book in question is Foundation and therefore a duplicate, however we have no acknowledgement that this has actually helped the user...

Comment: It's difficult when users ask a question then never come back... would moderators ever email a user to remind them to accept an answer? The unaccepted rate in [tag:story-identification] must be horrendous.

Comment: @PeterPeter No, that wouldn't be an appropriate user of mod access to PII. And yes, there are loads of unaccepted or even unanswered story-ID questions; [these tricks for searching](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9332/31394) will probably enable you to get some statistics if you're interested.