# How to deal with story ID questions with different details but the same answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, flagging

Say there exists a story ID question that lists details A and B and has an accepted answer.

If a user posts another question that lists details C and D and you're absolutely sure that the answer is the same as the first question, should the second one be marked as a duplicate?

On the one hand both questions are asking about the same work, on the other they have different content.

Comment: We generally do not close story ID questions unless the user has indicated (through acceptance or a comment) that the answerer has found the right work. One *very* narrow exception that I've seen is when the same user reposts the same question.

Comment: Ironic that this is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is a fairly common occurrence with [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions.

Question 1 ...

> **Question 1 -** I'm thinking of a film that has metal people from the future trying to kill a woman named Sally.
>
> **A.** This is 'The Terminator'. The metal people are called Terminators and the heroine is actually called Sarah.

... is **still** a dupe of Question 2 ...

> **Question 2  -** I'm thinking of a film where a psychiatrist interviews a man from the future and doesn't believe him

... even though none of the points raised in Question 2 are addressed in the answer to Question 1. That's  just how we roll, I'm afraid.

---

We also have a policy

[Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance)

to prevent *potential* dupes being closed until there's an agreement from the OP that their question is actually a duplicate.

Comment: I think the asker was specifically addressing the case where only *one* question has an accepted answer. I thought they [both had to be accepted](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/51379) in order to dupe.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - I think he's asking both things, but without knowing what the policy is. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about the case where only one has an answer but it's good to know the other case as well.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

> If a user posts another question that lists details C and D and you're absolutely sure that the answer is the same as the first question, should the second one be marked as a duplicate?

**YES, where 'absolutely sure' is defined to mean 'the original posters of both questions have verified that the answers are correct'.**

This policy was agreed upon [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance).