# Was this story-ID question incorrectly closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

Last I read, the policy on duplicate story-ID questions was that they both had to have accepted answers.  This [one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139459/time-traveler-mistaken-for-senile-put-in-vr) that was just closed does not meet that criterion.

And it seems odd to close the one with an accepted answer, in favor of one that doesn't.

Not arguing, just asking if the policy changed.

Comment: I edited your title to make it clearer that you're asking about a specific question and this meta post isn't simply a dupe of the policy on story-ID dupe closures. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you link to was closed as a duplicate by the [Community ♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user, which means that the OP themselves agreed it was a duplicate; see [this announcement on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) for when Community dupe-closures became a thing.

This is fine when the old question has an accepted answer but the new one doesn't, since by agreeing that it's a dupe the OP of the new question is essentially accepting an answer. (Some *unanswered* story-ID questions have even been closed this way in the past.)

However, in the example you link to, the new question has an accepted answer but the old one doesn't. This means that in the unlikely event that the current answer to the older question turns out to be incorrect and a different answer is posted and accepted, the dupe-closure will no longer be valid according to [our policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?rq=1). In view of this, **I've reopened the question**.