# Story-id duplicate policy

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If we're still following the story-id duplicate policy, then [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242943/book-where-a-girl-breaks-into-a-spaceship-that-crashes-and-finds-a-boy-that-pull) should not have been closed, tempting though it is. Neither the question nor the proposed duplicate has any answers, much less any accetped ones. Did something change recently?

[This other Meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10119/was-this-story-id-question-incorrectly-closed-as-duplicate) is similar, but in that instance the question was closed by user  [Community ♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and the duplicate had an accepted answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Jeez, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We make an exception to the usual [policy on closing ID questions as dupes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31394) when **both questions were asked by the same person**.<sup>1</sup> Re-posting the same question again if you didn't get any answers at first is a no-no all over the SE network, as an answerless OP should instead use other options such as editing their original question or placing a bounty on it. We don't want people to use our story-ID dupe policy as a loophole to keep re-posting the same question as many times as they like until it's answered.

Note that I'm not implying the OP of this question had any bad intent. They're not a very active user, and it's reasonable to assume they simply didn't know about any rule against re-posting the same question. Nor am I implying that *you're* suggesting we should allow this loophole for re-posters, rather than simply not noticing that both questions were asked by the same user. Actually I'm glad you made this meta post, because this exception to the story-ID dupe rule has been our *practice* for quite a while but I don't think it's ever been codified as *policy* on meta before.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>As a general principle, this also covers cases where an OP has come back on a new account to post a near-identical question (common enough in story-ID where many OPs are one-shot wonders), although those cases may be harder to track down unless one of our story-ID watchers has an eagle eye or an eidetic memory. In this case, though, the OP used the same account for both questions.</sub>

Comment: [You seem to have answered this before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/58193), that’s probably a good meta policy for it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You know you're getting SE-old when you think there's no meta policy on something and then it turns out you wrote one yourself :-) Only a year ago too, but even after reading that meta it's still not ringing any bells in my mind.

Comment: To be honest I knew there was a meta on it but I thought _I’d_ answered it not you. So either there’s another I’m not finding or I’ve been around long enough to start conflating things.