# What's the best way to add details to a duplicated story-ID question?

Tags: discussion

I recently wrote a Story ID question after doing a few searches and, at the end of writing it, noticed a potential match in the "similar questions" to the right. Indeed, my question had been asked before, albeit with different details. I wound up keeping my question, and closing it as a duplicate (not of the one to the side, which was itself marked as a Duplicate, but of the question it was worked as a duplicate of). Do we have a policy? The closest I've found is Valorum stating that his belief is that [a comment should be posted to the OP](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10539/23243) with the additional details. The thing is, my understanding is that comments are not searchable, so the details would not actually help people to find the story in question.

Thoughts? Policy?

Comment: In that instance, the goal was to share comments with the OP that they might want to add to their own (unsolved) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't add extra details to a *solved* story-ID question.

It invalidates the question and stands a pretty reasonable chance of making the OP look like an idiot for not being able to answer their own question.

---

We've dealt with a similar issue here;  [Should we tag (solved) story identification questions with the name of the author / property?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-solved-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-autho)

Answer (score -1):

### Add a new question with as many details as you can add (including ones in the duplicated query), acknowledge the duplicate, and mark it as such

I feel like this is the best approach for the purpose of helping later querents. You get the additional data available for searching and an acknowledgement that it's been answered before.

### Issues

Except... that will create intentional duplicates. And it might take a bit before the question does get closed. And, without good writers, I could see that sort of a policy leading to "Me too" questions that consist of "Yeah, this book, and the protagonist wore a blue shirt at the beginning". Perhaps with a policy of deleting the dupe if the OP adds the details?

I just figured it best to put one possible answer up.

Comment: ... Or not. :-D

Comment: Side note, this approach was also covered in https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/is-it-bad-practice-to-ask-a-story-id-question-for-something-you-managed-to-find?noredirect=1&lq=1