# How should we handle [story-identification] questions that are word-for-word duplicates (or slightly reworded versions) of a prior question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, story-identification

There are these two [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions that seem to be asking to identify the same thing:

- [Anime with boy who can grow crystals on his body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251299/7957), posted in July 2021 and currently unanswered
- [Anime where the MC is a boy who can grow green crystals/gems on his body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270696/7957), posted in December 2022 and currently has one answer with two upvotes but has not been accepted by the OP

The similarities between the questions indicate that they are both asking to identify the same anime. (I've commented about this on the later question.) Another user pointed out that the later question "is word-for-word the same as the previous question." (The OP of the later question has slightly reworded their question and added a screenshot of the anime.) This means that either both questions were posted by the same person or the second question was copied from the first (is a duplicate).

**Should we close one of these questions as a duplicate or should we leave them open?**

Comment: It reminds me that a recent question was a verbatim copy of an older one, but with only 1 extra sentence. They were closed as duplicate (don't remember whether or not they were answered). I would like to believe it's pretty safe to close this one for the same reasons, seeing that it's clearly the same question with some rephrasing. There's also the possibility someone copied another question as an inspiration to ask theirs, but then the plot would be slightly more divergent than that about how it ends.

Comment: In the past, I've flagged these for moderator attention just in case it was the same person re-asking. Every time I checked, mods closed the new question as a duplicate (or deleted it).