# Should I answer a question I know to be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Re the question: [Book of short stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156306/book-of-short-stories)

It's a duplicate of several other questions:

- [Trying to find the name of a sci fi anthology book, or just the titles of one or more stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143593/trying-to-find-the-name-of-a-sci-fi-anthology-book-or-just-the-titles-of-one-or)
- [Short story about mutant children who all have names starting with "Em"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/short-story-about-mutant-children-who-all-have-names-starting-with-em)
- [Looking for late 70s short story anthology, we'd call it YA now. May have included Leiber's "A Pail of Air"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/looking-for-late-70s-short-story-anthology-wed-call-it-ya-now-may-have-includ)

What is the official policy regarding such questions. Answering it seems a bit of a rep grab, but on the other hand not answering it leaves it dangling unanswered. I guess the best option would be for the OP to agree it's a duplicate so we can close it, but so far they show no signs of doing so.

Comment: Hmm, sure, why not? I don't know if there is an official policy on answering dupes, but I can say I've answered some duplicate questions myself, and then have gone on to close the question as a duplicate immediately afterward (I have a gold *Harry Potter* badge, so I can close HP questions as duplicates). Yes, it gets me (probably minimal) points, but that *is* the point of the site <sub>besides helping to make the internet a better place</sub>.  :)

Comment: Our official policy is partially detailed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1). We only close as dupes where there's an acceptance from both parties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already have an agreed policy on closing duplicate [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) questions, that we only close them as duplicates where there's agreement from both parties that their questions are asking about the same property. **It doesn't matter how "obvious" you think they are, if they aren't accepted, we don't dupe them off.**

[Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

As far as *new* questions are concerned, you have two choices;

- **You can post a comment to the OP that you think their question is a dupe, preferably with a link to the suspected duplicate**

> "I think this is x, as detailed in the question [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1)".

If the OP agrees, you can then mark it as a duplicate. This is the preferred option if the new question doesn't really add any extra details to the already answered question, or is a dupe of a dupe of a dupe.

- **If you feel the need, you can post a new answer.**

This is the preferable option where the other question doesn't already have an accepted answer or where the question adds significant detail (such as asking about a single story in an anthology).

Answer (score 0):

I always feel like it's worth posting an answer both because there's a chance that it's not actually a duplicate, and also because it gives you a chance to provide an even better answer with more details.

Comment: And also, in the case of questions by new users, because there's a good chance we will never hear from them again.