# Can a identification question be marked as a duplicate of a question with no accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, story-identification

I believe that these two questions have the same answer.

[Anime: main character equips a horned helmet to fight monsters/criminals, pulls out a sword from his arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208598/anime-main-character-equips-a-horned-helmet-to-fight-monsters-criminals-pulls/208607#208607)

[Anime: Dying alien robot merge his head with an human and gives him armor to keep fighting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209296/anime-dying-alien-robot-merge-his-head-with-an-human-and-gives-him-armor-to-kee/209305#209305)

In fact I've answered them both, but the first question doesn't have an accepted answer.

So should the second question be marked as a duplicate in this instance?

Comment: No, confirmation from the OP is needed. Confirmation doesn't need to be an accepted answer, could be a comment, an edit a comment elsewhere etc. but the OP needs to confirm the work is correct.

Comment: *If* both of your answers are confirmed by the OP (either by acceptance or just a comment), then yes, we'll close them as dupes.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Per consensus on [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/):

> [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions should only be closed as duplicates where both answers are accepted, regardless of the similarity between them. (If the OP posts a "yes this is it" comment, that's as good as an acceptance.)
>
> Simple, easy to administer.

In this case neither answer got accepted, may that be in comments or checkmark, so both stay open.

The only exception might be if an user re-posted their story-id question instead of editing it; in which case, if it's obvious the works looked for are the same (not based on answers but the combination of same OP+same question), then we can close as dupe, and merge after that.