# My question was closed as a duplicate but it's not really a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question of mine, [Which sci-fi book is this quote from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242723/which-sci-fi-book-is-this-quote-from), was closed as a duplicate of this other question, [What is Series Where There is an AI Born on the Solar System-Wide Network](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95417/what-is-series-where-there-is-an-ai-born-on-the-solar-system-wide-network).

I can see why that happened: the answer to the two questions *is the same* (book 2 of Ender's Saga, *Speaker for the Dead*). But my question *is not* a duplicate of the other one. In fact, reading that other question and answer before asking my question would have had no impact, as I would not have realized that it was that book I was looking for. (I didn't even know that the "girl" character in the quote I remembered was an AI!)

So why was my question considered a duplicate?

Comment: Looks like it was closed due to the [[tag:story-identification]] [duplicate policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/58193): if two id requests have the same confirmed answer they are duplicates. However, your question is kind of in a grey area on whether it really fits into that policy in my opinion because you seem to have been more looking for the quote rather than the specific book (though you were looking for both).

Comment: FWIW what was you actually after in the question, the book or the quote?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I wasn't aware of that policy and that actually makes sense. I was after the quote, so I asked if anyone knew the book so I could get to the quote :)

Comment: Okay, you could edit the question to specify you're after the quote (and also the book) rather than the book (and also the quote) if you want and I think that'd be enough to get it reopened and also shouldn't invalidate the answer. But that is up to you, I don't suppose it really needs to be reopened.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the other question also asks about a series (i.e. the Enderverse) rather than a specific book. So I wouldn't say that the answers, strictly, are duplicates. But having been answered I agree that re-opening the question is a bit academic.

Comment: Perhaps ironically, I've now closed this meta post as a duplicate, since your issue seems well enough addressed by the dupe policy that you weren't aware of. Note that duplicates are considered more valuable than other closed questions: new answers can't be posted, like any closed question, but duplicates have value as signposts, and many of the automatic processes that work against closed questions actually disregard duplicate questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor fair - I agree with this one being closed as a duplicate. not really the other one but as it was pointed out, not much sense in reopening :)