# Should a querent be able to identify their question as the dupe of a question that has a matching unaccepted answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, story-identification

Ran into [Story about students stuck in a black and white universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83557/story-about-students-stuck-in-a-black-and-white-universe?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a result of following some breadcrumbs from the Literature SE, and I noticed that [What is this story I'm trying to remember, set in an alternate black and white dimension?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177556/what-is-this-story-im-trying-to-remember-set-in-an-alternate-black-and-white-d?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed by its querent as a duplicate of the former even though the duplicate target has no accepted answer. Should we allow that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a word, no. The duplicate target doesn't have an accepted answer which means that it's [not a suitable dupe target](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance).

OP should write up a self-answer and then accept it.