# Should Duplicate Story ID questions be answered or commented?

Tags: discussion

Is there a best practice for obvious duplicate story ID questions?

Specifically is it better to link the duplicate in a comment or provide an answer with that link and the corroborating details?

The duplicate close [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?rq=1) asks for both questions to have accepted answers, suggesting providing an answer is the preferred choice?

Comment: In some very rare case, I feel like the dupe is so obvious that an answer is not even needed, such as when the question is a verbatim copy for example, although some tropes are so common that two stories can be mistaken for one another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the 'obvious dupe' target (Q1) doesn't have an accepted answer, then the best practice for the new question (Q2) would be to;

- Write an answer (allowing the author of Q2 to accept the answer)
- Prod the author of (Q1) to accept the answer so that we can dupe one to the other.

This has the benefit of allowing the new question to be used as the closure target for future dupe questions.

---

If the dupe target has an accepted answer, then it's up to you. Personally if it's really obvious and the question was asked very recently I'll take a chance that the asker is still on the site and just post a comment asking them if x is a dupe. If they answer in the affirmative, then I'll close it on the strength of their comment.

Comment: I'm troubled by the "accepted answer" criterion. I see too many questions where the accepted answer is plainly wrong, doesn't actually answer the question, or does, but should have been superseded by a better (and often more highly scoring) later answer.

Comment: @MarkOlson - Can you give an example of an answer that's wrong?

Comment: @MarkOlson - And if you feel the dupe target on a question should be reversed, why not post a meta suggesting that it be done (rather than merely suffering in silence)?

Comment: (1) Not off-hand. (It doesn't happen often -- accepted answers which are not the best answer seem more common.) (2) My impression is that the community has a fairly ingrained tradition of quickly closing questions as duplicate, and I've sworn an oath (which I occasionally keep) to avoid pointless arguments.

Comment: @MarkOlson - The goal is tidiness. It's best not to think of a question being closed as a punishment, but rather as us erecting a signpost that says *"your answer is over here"*

Answer (score 8):

If I can provide information that specifically addresses things in the duplicate question, I prefer to post a new answer.  People remember, and ask about, different aspects of stories, and it can be helpful to have an answer that points out how the elements mentioned in the duplicate question match the work.